# i need to update table records in magento?

Tags: magento2, database

```
 "UPDATE mytable SET column1 = value1, column2 = value2, ... WHERE status = 'pending'";
```

**how can i write above query in magento2 ?**

> I try this.

```
$postData = $objectManager->create('vendor\module\Model\PostFactory');
        $arrayData = [ 
                        'status' =>'send'
                    ];
 $sql = $postData->create()
                 ->setData($arrayData)
                 ->load('status',array('eq'=>'pending'))
                 ->save();
```

Comment: check this link - https://www.rakeshjesadiya.com/how-to-create-mysql-update-query-using-magento-2/

Comment: Don't use object manager directly , create object in constructor and use that instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Try this code

```
echo "<pre>";
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
//vendor\module\Model\PostFactory
$post = $objectManager->Create('\vendor\module\Model\ResourceModel\Post\Collection')->addFieldToFilter('status','pending');

foreach ($post as $key => $value) {
    //print_r($value->getId());
    $post_data = $objectManager->Create('\vendor\module\Model\Post')->load($value->getId());
    $post_data->setColumn1('value1');
    $post_data->setColumn2('value2');
    $post_data->save();
}

print_r($post->getData());
```

> if column name is **create_data** then it should be like **setCreateData()** and column name is **status** then it should be like **setStatus()**.

***I Hope This Helps You***